# Updating a field after a failed Validation

Tags: jsf, primefaces, client-side-validation

I am building a web application using the technologies mentioned in the post header. I have searched similar threads, but none of them provided an answer to my problem. I have configured my Maven project, the pom file is correct, JSF and PrimeFaces are working, but I encounter a problem when I do the following:

I copied the Client Side Validation example from the Prime Faces Showcase website, and on my end, it isn't working as expected.

When validation fails for a field, an error appears to the right of the field, and as long as it's there, I cannot update the field. When I try to type something, nothing happens on the screen, but if I highlight the text in the field, I can see it there.

Here's my registration.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        Hello from Facelets

        <h2>Registration Form</h2>
        <h:form id="form">
            <p:panel id="panel" header="Form" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                <p:fieldset legend="Registration Form" widgetVar="regWidget" style="width: 600px;">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="3" width="550" border="0">
                        <h:outputLabel value="UserName" />
                        <p:inputText value="#{regCont.prospect.userName}" 
                                     id="userName"
                                     required="true" 
                                     requiredMessage="UserName is required"
                                     validatorMessage="UserName should be of length from 5 to 15 chars"
                                     >
                            <f:validateLength minimum="5" maximum="15" for="userName"></f:validateLength>
                        </p:inputText>
                        <p:message for="userName"/>


                        <h:outputLabel value="Password" />
                        <p:password value="#{regCont.password}"
                                    id="password"
                                    required="true" 
                                    requiredMessage="Password is required"
                                    validatorMessage="Password should be of length from 5 to 15 chars"
                                    >
                            <f:validateRegex pattern="^(?=^.{8,12}$)(?!.*(.)\1{3,})(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]{3,})(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9]{2,})(?=.*[0-9]{2,})[a-zA-Z]"/>

                        </p:password>
                        <p:message for="password" />

                        <h:outputLabel value="FirstName" />
                        <p:inputText value="#{regCont.prospect.firstName}"
                                     id="firstName"
                                     required="true" 
                                     requiredMessage="FirstName is required"
                                     validatorMessage="FirstName should be of length from 5 to 15 chars"
                                     >
                            <f:validateLength minimum="1" maximum="45" for="firstName"></f:validateLength>
                        </p:inputText>
                        <p:message for="firstName" display="tooltip" />


                        <h:outputLabel value="LastName" />
                        <p:inputText value="#{regCont.prospect.lastName}"
                                     id="lastName"></p:inputText>
                        <p:message for="lastName" display="tooltip"/>

                        <h:outputLabel value="Email" />
                        <p:inputText value="#{regCont.prospect.email}"
                                     id="email"
                                     validatorMessage="Invalid Email">
                            <f:validateRegex pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}"></f:validateRegex> 
                        </p:inputText>
                        <p:message for="email" />

                        <h:outputLabel value="Nation" />
                        <p:inputText value="#{regCont.prospect.nation}"
                                     id="nation">
                        </p:inputText>
                        <p:message for="nation" />

                        <h3 style="margin-top:0">User type</h3>
                        <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px" cellpadding="5">
                            <p:outputLabel for="type" value="User type:" />
                            <p:selectOneRadio id="type" value="#{regCont.prospect.userType}">
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Delegate" itemValue="Delegate" />
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Leader" itemValue="Leader" />
                            </p:selectOneRadio>
                        </h:panelGrid>

                        <p:commandButton value="Register" update="panel" icon="ui-icon-check" validateClient="true" style="margin-right:10px"/>

                        <h:commandButton value="Reset p:ajax" style="margin-right:20px;" >
                            <p:ajax update="panel" resetValues="true" />
                        </h:commandButton>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:fieldset>
            </p:panel>
        </h:form>


    </h:body>
</html>
```

And here's my RegistrationController class:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "regCont")
@RequestScoped
public class RegistrationController implements Controller {

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{prospect}")
    private Prospect prospect;
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{user}")
    private User user;
    private String msg;
    private String password;

    public void hashPassword() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        byte[] salt = Passwords.getNextSalt();
        prospect.setSalt(salt);
        prospect.setPasswordHash(Passwords.getHashWithSalt(password, salt));
        password = "";
    }

    public Prospect getProspect() {
        return prospect;
    }

    public void setProspect(Prospect prospect) {
        this.prospect = prospect;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    private void clearAll() {
        user.setFirstName("");
        user.setLastName("");
        user.setNation("");
        user.setEmail("");
        user.setUserName("");
        user.setPasswordHash(null);

        prospect.setFirstName("");
        prospect.setLastName("");
        prospect.setNation("");
        prospect.setEmail("");
        prospect.setUserType("");
        prospect.setUserName("");
        prospect.setPasswordHash(null);
    }

    public void saveUser() {
        UserDAO dao = new UserDAO();
        dao.createEntity(user);
        this.msg = "Member Info Saved Successfull!";
        clearAll();
    }

    public void saveProspect() {
        ProspectDAO dao = new ProspectDAO();
        try {
            hashPassword();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(User.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        dao.createEntity(prospect);
        this.msg = "Member Info Saved Successfull!";
    }

    public void reset() {
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().reset("form");
    }

    public void updateUser(int id) {
        UserDAO dao = new UserDAO();
        try {
            hashPassword();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(User.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        dao.updateEntity(id);
        this.msg = "Member Info Update Successfull!";
        clearAll();
    }

    public void deleteUser(int id) {
        UserDAO dao = new UserDAO();
        dao.deleteEntity(id);
        this.msg = "Member Info Delete Successfull!";
        clearAll();
    }

}
```

Only case this works is, when I implemented the Reset button, and on a failed validation, I click reset, then I can input values into fields.

Also, when I hover above a field (p:inputText), the cursor doesn't change to the text cursor like on other fields (eg. h:inputText). Really don't have an idea how does the same piece of code work on the PrimeFaces ShowCase web site, and not on my end?

Does anybody have an idea how can I fix this?

I'm using JSF 2.2 + PrimeFaces 5.3

Comment: Jsf 2.2 what? Mojarra / Myfaces? And specific version please. And please try to create an [mcve] amd compare the real full showcase from github with your code. Find the differences.

Comment: I use Tomcat 8 for server and Mojarra implementation.
The problem is when I use p:inputText, fields act in a bad way, if there is an validation error, they freeze, I can't update them, unless I implement a clear button like in the example

Comment: Mojara version is 2.2.2, problem is, when I copy a piece of code from PrimeFaces Showcase, it acts different on my end, then on the PF website, and I copy the same piece of code

Comment: Mojarra 2.2.26 does not exist yet, so that can't be. And if you copied a piece, copy more, copy things from github, not the showcase website